# freebsd set quota for users per zfs share

Tags: freebsd, quota

Is there any way to set multi quota for a user?

**example:**

I have a zfs pool named storage, three folder are in this folder, now, I want to:

user1 has 10G on /storage/folder1

user1 has 5G on /storage/folder2

user1 has 100M /storage/folder3
.
.
.

I'm on freeBSD11.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you create a dataset from each directory, and then set the *userquota* property for *user1* on each of these datasets for a desired value.